# How to validate a path given in an inputdialog?

Tags: validation, vim, input

I'm trying to validate a path given in an inputdialog.

```
   "a = path to file p.e. d:\mydoc.txt (but can be every file)
   let a = inputdialog(docinput)

   while 1
    try
      read (a)
        catch /E484:/
        echo "The file doesn't exist"
        let a = inputdialog(docinput,a,"return") 
        if a == "return" 
          return
        endif
    endtry
   endwhile
```

I want to check if the filename exists using the `read` command.
But it seems that `read` cannot read a variable.
`read` has to be something like this:
`read d:\mydoc.txt`

1) How can I read a variable?

If `read` gives an error message (E484 (cannot read the file)), the script has to return to the inputdialog.
I tried to do this with a try/endtry within a while/endwhile loop but I haven't found out how to break out of the loop.

2) How can I return the script to the inputdialog if the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must use `:execute` to `:read` the filename contained in variable `a`:

  ```
  execute "read " . a
  ```
- `:read` is the wrong tool for the job, use `filereadable()` (or `filewriteable()`, depending on what you want to do with that file) instead:

  ```
  if filereadable(expand(a))
    " do something
  else
    " do something else
  endif
  ```

I can't understand your second question.

Comment: Romainl, thank you! filereadable did the trick. :) It resolved also my  2nd question. Btw.. I updated my 2nd question for the readers.